# Replacing categorical values in a vector to numbers

Tags: r

I have a data frame

```
t = data.frame(c(5,5,5), c('a','b','c', 'a', 'b', 'd'), c(1,2,3), c(1,2,3))
```

And vector with rownames

```
vector = table(t$V2)
```

How do I replace second categorical column in a dataframe with numbers from a vector?

I've did some google foo and tried to do the following:

```
map = setNames(vector, rownames(vector))
to_replace = t$V2
to_replace[] = map[unlist(map)]
```

But I am getting an error:

```
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, , value = c(146L, 146L, 27L, 82L, 110L,  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
```

EDIT

Sorry guys, I did not make clear what I wanted to do

t$V2 and vector have different length. Basically vector with rownames is a map itself. I want to match rownames in vector to values in t$V2 and replace it with values of vector. Vector itself was generated using table(t$V2) function.

Comment: presumably you mean `names(vector)` (not `rownames(vector)`) in line 3

Comment: I am not sure, but I've edited my post to make it clearer.

Comment: `rownames(vector)` produces an error both for me and @42 (see below)

Comment: rownames works for me if I generate vector from dataframe using table() function.

Comment: Yup, because then `vector` isn't stored as a vector--hence the different behavior from the original version of the post :)

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to execute `rownames(vector) = c('a', 'b', 'c')` I got an error. The `rownames<-`-function will not succeed when the target is just an atomic vector. So that also means that `map = setNames(vector, rownames(vector))` would not succeed, so we need to do this:

```
map = setNames(vector, c('a', 'b', 'c'))  # success
```

But now we have further problem because you are not telling us what expect the result to be, and this `map[unlist(map)]` isn't really sensible as something to assign:

```
> map[unlist(map)]   # there are no 4 or 6 positon in `vector` or `map`
   b <NA> <NA> 
   4   NA   NA
```

If all you wanted was to replace V2 with that numeric vector, it would just be

```
t$V2 <- vector
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
t = data.frame(v1 = c(5,5,5), v2 = c('a','b','c'), v3 = c(1,2,3), v4 = c(1,2,3))
vector = c(2,4,6)
row.names(t) <- vector

print(t)
# Output from print(t)
  v1 v2 v3 v4
2  5  a  1  1
4  5  b  2  2
6  5  c  3  3
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the column of intersest in your dataframe is type `factor`. Check out the following code, with and without the hashed line.

```
t <- data.frame(c(5,5,5), c('a','b','c'), c(1,2,3), c(1,2,3))
vector <- c(2,4,6,8)
names(vector) <- c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')

# t[,2] <- as.character(t[,2])

for(i in 1:dim(t)[1]){
  t[i,2] <- vector[which(names(vector)==t[i,2])]
}
```